# New to abstracts etc Cannot instantiate the type

Tags: java, arrays, object, interface

Hello everyone I am having trouble writing my program since it keeps giving me the error: Cannot Instantiate the type. I'm new to abstracts/implements so I suspect that to be the problem with this program. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.net.URL; 
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public  class Program5 {

    public  abstract static class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>{
        String OwnerName;
        int birthYear;
        public int billBalance;
        String Species;
        String feature;
        public  Animal() {}
        public Animal(String OwnerName,int birthYear,int billBalance,String Species,String feature) {
            this.OwnerName = OwnerName;
            this.birthYear = birthYear;
            this.billBalance = billBalance;
            this.Species = Species;
            this.feature = feature;
        }
        public void storeFile(Animal[] x) throws Exception{
            BigInteger size = new BigInteger("1");
            URL url=new URL("http://yoda.com/~pawang/CPS1/Program5_veterinarian_input.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            conn.getInputStream();
            size = BigInteger.valueOf(conn.getContentLength());
            while (input.hasNext()){
                for(int i = 1;i<size.bitLength();i++) {
                    x[i] = new Animal();
                    String line = input.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
        public int getBalance() {
            return billBalance;
        }
        public static void sorts(Animal[] x) {

        }
    }
}
```

It seems the problem is on line 33 : x[i] = new Animal();

Comment: Your class shouldn't be abstract if you want to instantiate it.

Comment: What do you think *abstract class* means?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi Yes but if I don't do that the error will tell me I have to do that to fix it. So confused

Comment: `implements Comparable` seems to be a *lie* regarding that class - it is not implementing it, and since there are missing methods, the class should be `abstract` and no instance can be created

Comment: You can remove abstract keyword from class declaration and instantiate your Animal class as simple class, or you can declare abstract class Animal and also create class e.g. Dog which extend Animal class, and finally instantiate Dog class

Answer (score 0):

Abstract means that there is something in the class only declared, and never defined.
For example, image a class `Person` that is being created to be extended, and have a method `doThings`:  let's say that we create `Worker` and `Student` classes, `Worker` on the `doThings` should work, instead `Student` should study, where instead `Person` doesn't have to do anything, but in order to have inheritance, and so do something like `ArrayList<Person>` and then on each element, call `doThings`, we must have a `doThing` method on each element, but as already said, `Person` doesn't have to do anything... so in the `Person` class we just declare the `doThing` method like this:

```
public void abstract doThing();
```

With this statement we are telling the JVM that whenever we have an object of this type, there is a `doThing` method, also if we don't implement this: and this is why you can't create a new object if the class is abstract, because something declared is never been implemented.
If you want to instantiate objects of that class, you should create a new class that is overriding the abstract methods.

This is just a brief explanation, there is a lot more behind and a lot more thing you can do with this.

Comment: thank you for the sinigh on that explanation. I only made it abstract since when I implented the Comparable it said that I needed to make the class abstract.

Comment: yes, exactly because you have not implemented the compareTo, so the compare to is abstract